# Accessing members of a struct in a vector

Tags: c, pointers, vector, struct

I am looping through an `XML` file successfully and storing data into a `struct` before attempting to store that `struct's` pointer into a `vector` (I think). But when I attempt to access the data immediately after I can only access the most recently added `struct`, no matter which index I access.

`struct` in question:

```
typedef struct
{
    double   trueHeadingRadians;
    double   latitude;
    double   latitudeRadians; 
    double   longitude;  
    double   longitudeRadians; 
    .
    .
} wayPoint;
```

relevant `vector` functions:

```
typedef struct 
{
    void         **items;
    unsigned int capacity;
    unsigned int total;
} vector;

// intitiaizes vector struct
void vectorInit(vector* v)
{
    v->capacity = VECTOR_INIT_CAPACITY;  // 4
    v->total = 0;
    v->items = malloc(sizeof(void* ) * v->capacity);
}

// resizes vector
static void vectorResize(vector* v, int capacity)
{
    void** items = realloc(v->items, sizeof(void* ) * capacity);
    if( items ) 
    {
        v->items = items;
        v->capacity = capacity;
    }
}

// returns total number of members in vector
unsigned int vectorTotal(vector *v)
{
    return v->total;
}

// adds element to vector
void vectorAdd(vector* v, void* item)
{
    if( v->capacity == v->total )
    {
        vectorResize(v, v->capacity * 2);
    }

    v->items[v->total++] = item;
}

// gets item from vector
void* vectorGet(vector* v, unsigned int index)
{

    if( index >= 0 && index < v->total )
    {   
        return v->items[index];
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

So now I add values to a `struct` before adding the `struct`'s `void pointer` to the vector.

```
vector simDataVector;
vectorInit(&simDataVector);

wayPoint pointStruct = {0};
pointStruct.latitude = 37.415000;
.
.
// add struct pointer to vector
vectorAdd(&simDataVector, &pointStruct);
printf("length of vector: %u\n", vectorTotal(&simDataVector));

// THIS IS WHERE I THINK THE ISSUE IS -- AM I DEREFERENCING THIS PROPERLY?
printf("latitude = %f\n", ((wayPoint* )vectorGet(&simDataVector, indx))->latitude);
```

this output is:

```
length of vector: 1     // whichever index I am currently on
latitude = 37.415000    // the most recently added struct's latitude
```

which is correct every time through the loop! The vector can track the size properly as well as the data. Until after the initialization. When I try to print out each wayPoint `struct` for testing, each index displays the data of the most recently added wayPoint `struct`. I am so confused here.

Comment: These lines `wayPoint pointStruct = {0};
wayPoint.latitude = 37.415000` don't compile, even when you add the missing semicolon.  It should be `pointStruct.latitude` on the second line, shouldn't it?

Comment: You've not shown where `indx` is defined or how it is set to a value, either.  What is its value?  When you add another point to the vector, are you continuing to pass `&pointStruct` to it?  If so, you're trying to store lots of different values in a single variable and it can't manage more than one (the latest one) at any given time.  I suspect this is your problem.  It would be a lot easier to be decisive if you showed us an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: @HappyCoder: because C is not C++.

Comment: Oh, it is tagged `C`. My bad!

Comment: Sorry for the missed semicolon and wayPoint vs pointStruct typos, I'll add that. But indx is defined in a for loop. I mention in the very beginning that I am looping through an XML file and retrieving values.

Answer (score 2):

It's odd that you seem to have a good grasp on memory, based on your vector implementation, but you forgot to copy the actual data when you add it.  Instead you've just passed a pointer to your local variable like this:

```
vectorAdd(&simDataVector, &pointStruct);
```

Instead you need to allocate storage (given the current design of your vector).  Perhaps wrap that in a function:

```
void wayPointAdd( vector * v, const wayPoint * p )
{
    wayPoint * data = malloc( sizeof(wayPoint) );
    if( data )
    {
        *data = *p;
        vectorAdd( v, data );
    }
}
```

Comment: Copying the data is not necessary if the object with that data is not deleted while the vector exists.

Comment: @paddy your observation would be valid only in the case that `pointstruct` goes out of scope when it's being accessed. That doesn't seem to be the case in the OP's problem. A pointer to valid memory is what's being passed to the `vectorAdd` function

Comment: If you read the last paragraph in the question, the OP indicates that the code sample for insertion is being performed in a loop.  After the loop, they say that every item in the vector contains the same value.  It was quite clear to me that this _IS_ the OP's problem.